# Wordpress shortcode function for generating svg icons

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, svg, shortcode

I have created a Wordpress function called `svg_icon()`, to print/echo inline svg icons.

I want to print an inline svg based on an array's key and attributes.

Here is my function code

```
function svg_icon($atts = array()) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts([
        'icon' => false,
        'label' => false,
    ], $atts);

    if (empty($atts['icon']))
        return;

    $config = [
        'arrow' => [
            '<svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path d="M21.883 12l-7.527 6.235.644.765 9-7.521-9-7.479-.645.764 7.529 6.236h-21.884v1h21.883z"/></svg>'
        ],
        'hamburger' => [
            '<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m13 16.745c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-9.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h9.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75zm9-5c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-18.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h18.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75zm-4-5c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-14.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h14.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75z" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>'
        ],
        'close' => [
            '<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m12.002 2.005c5.518 0 9.998 4.48 9.998 9.997 0 5.518-4.48 9.998-9.998 9.998-5.517 0-9.997-4.48-9.997-9.998 0-5.517 4.48-9.997 9.997-9.997zm0 1.5c-4.69 0-8.497 3.807-8.497 8.497s3.807 8.498 8.497 8.498 8.498-3.808 8.498-8.498-3.808-8.497-8.498-8.497zm0 7.425 2.717-2.718c.146-.146.339-.219.531-.219.404 0 .75.325.75.75 0 .193-.073.384-.219.531l-2.717 2.717 2.727 2.728c.147.147.22.339.22.531 0 .427-.349.75-.75.75-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.219l-2.729-2.728-2.728 2.728c-.146.146-.338.219-.53.219-.401 0-.751-.323-.751-.75 0-.192.073-.384.22-.531l2.728-2.728-2.722-2.722c-.146-.147-.219-.338-.219-.531 0-.425.346-.749.75-.749.192 0 .385.073.531.219z" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>'
        ]
    ];

    if (array_key_exists($atts['icon'], $config)) {
        $repl = '<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" ';
        $svg = preg_replace('/^<svg /', $repl, trim($atts['icon']));

        $svg = preg_replace("/([\n\t]+)/", ' ', $svg); // Remove newlines & tabs.
        $svg = preg_replace('/>\s*</', '><', $svg); // Remove white space between SVG tags.

        if (!empty($atts['label'])) {
            $svg = str_replace('<svg ', '<svg aria-label="'. esc_attr($atts['label']) .'"', $svg);
            $svg = str_replace('aria-hidden="true"', '', $svg);
        }

        return $svg;
    }
}
```

printing svg icon.

```
echo svg_icon([
    'icon' => 'hamburger',
    'label' => 'Main Menu',
]);
```

I'm having a problem. It's printing only the first `$config` array key (arrow) and nothing else.

Comment: This seems overly complicated for such a small set of values, and I’m unclear why preg_replace is needed. Also, in the first preg_replace, I think `$atts['icon']` should be `$config[$atts['icon']]`, if I’m understanding what is attempting to happen

Comment: Where are the new lines and tabs coming in in the first place that you are removing?

Comment: getting this error. 
Uncaught TypeError: trim(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Comment: Please remodify my function, i'm new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of things that I'd clean up in your function.

First, WordPress's `shortcode_atts` can usually be replaced with PHP's null coalescing operator in user-land code. (The `shortcode_atts` function also makes a final call to a hook which is why I wouldn't recommend removing it from core or plugins.)

Second, arrays are great for storing things, but I think it really makes code more readable when you can get variables, so I'm pulling the two keys into dedicated variables.

Third, in Sanjay Dihora's original post, they were trying to say that you were using an array of arrays, but you just need an array of strings, so I simplified that.

Fourth, your first `preg_replace` call attempted to add code to the selected SVG each time, and that's not necessary, just add that code to the SVGs in the array.

Fifth, no need for the whitespace clean up, the SVGs are already clean as-is.

Lastly, I added some type signatures to the function.

Below is the updated version. The spirit of what you were attempting is mostly here, so I wouldn't say you were very far off. There was just some complicated things that could be simplified.

```php
function svg_icon(array $atts = []): ?string
{
    // Get the provided values or a default value
    $icon = $atts['icon'] ?? false;
    $label = $atts['label'] ?? false;
    
    // This is required, so if it not set bail
    if (!$icon) {
        return null;
    }
    
    // These are our possible SVGs
    static $config = [
        'arrow' => '<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path d="M21.883 12l-7.527 6.235.644.765 9-7.521-9-7.479-.645.764 7.529 6.236h-21.884v1h21.883z"/></svg>',
        'hamburger' => '<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m13 16.745c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-9.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h9.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75zm9-5c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-18.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h18.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75zm-4-5c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-14.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h14.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75z" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>',
        'close' => '<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m12.002 2.005c5.518 0 9.998 4.48 9.998 9.997 0 5.518-4.48 9.998-9.998 9.998-5.517 0-9.997-4.48-9.997-9.998 0-5.517 4.48-9.997 9.997-9.997zm0 1.5c-4.69 0-8.497 3.807-8.497 8.497s3.807 8.498 8.497 8.498 8.498-3.808 8.498-8.498-3.808-8.497-8.498-8.497zm0 7.425 2.717-2.718c.146-.146.339-.219.531-.219.404 0 .75.325.75.75 0 .193-.073.384-.219.531l-2.717 2.717 2.727 2.728c.147.147.22.339.22.531 0 .427-.349.75-.75.75-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.219l-2.729-2.728-2.728 2.728c-.146.146-.338.219-.53.219-.401 0-.751-.323-.751-.75 0-.192.073-.384.22-.531l2.728-2.728-2.722-2.722c-.146-.147-.219-.338-.219-.531 0-.425.346-.749.75-.749.192 0 .385.073.531.219z" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>',
    ];
    
    // If the requested icon doesn't exist, bail
    if (!$svg = $config[$icon] ?? null) {
        return null;
    }
    
    // If we have a label, un-hide the SVG and set the ARIA attribute
    if (!empty($label)) {
        $svg = str_replace('<svg ', '<svg aria-label="'.esc_attr($label).'"', $svg);
        $svg = str_replace('aria-hidden="true"', '', $svg);
    }

    return $svg;

}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/HHWJKW#v8.2.6

One thing I would note is that I'm hoping this is expected to be run as a shortcode. If that's not the case, I would encourage you to simplify this code even further to just this: https://3v4l.org/UvAjF#v8.2.6

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code lies in the $config array structure. Each key in the $config array should have a corresponding array of SVG strings. Currently, you have defined each SVG string as a separate array element, causing the function to only return the first key-value pair from $config.

```php
$config = [
    'arrow' => '<svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path d="M21.883 12l-7.527 6.235.644.765 9-7.521-9-7.479-.645.764 7.529 6.236h-21.884v1h21.883z"/></svg>',
    'hamburger' => '<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m13 16.745c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-9.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h9.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75zm9-5c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-18.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h18.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75zm-4-5c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-14.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h14.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75z" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>',
    'close' => '<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m12.002 2.005c5.518 0 9.998 4.48 9.998 9.997 0 5.518-4.48 9.998-9.998 9.998-5.517 0-9.997-4.48-9.997-9.998 0-5.517 4.48-9.997 9.997-9.997zm0 1.5c-4.69 0-8.497 3.807-8.497 8.497s3.807 8.498 8.497 8.498 8.498-3.808 8.498-8.498-3.808-8.497-8.498-8.497zm0 7.425 2.717-2.718c.146-.146.339-.219.531-.219.404 0 .75.325.75.75 0 .193-.073.384-.219.531l-2.717 2.717 2.727 2.728c.147.147.22.339.22.531 0 .427-.349.75-.75.75-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.219l-2.729-2.728-2.728 2.728c-.146.146-.338.219-.53.219-.401 0-.751-.323-.751-.75 0-.192.073-.384.22-.531l2.728-2.728-2.722-2.722c-.146-.147-.219-.338-.219-.531 0-.425.346-.749.75-.749.192 0 .385.073.531.219z" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>',
];
```

Comment: Does'nt work...

Comment: The previous edit to this answer vastly changed it, so I rolled it back and applied some formatting. @Sanjay is correct, the OP had an array of arrays, and only an array of strings is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with some but not all of ChrisHaas's answer.

1. The `shortcode_atts()` call is not beneficial for your current processing.  If there is no icon value passed in, or the passed in value is not a key in your svg lookup array, then return `null` early.
2. Abstract the common elements from your svg strings.  This will remove code duplication/bloat and improve visibility and maintainability.
3. Use `sprintf()` to cleanly supply the svg template string with its variable-based markup.
4. It doesn't make sense for your lookup array to be two dimensional.  It also doesn't make sense to manipulate your markup string with `str_replace()`. Whether it make a replacement or not, it will still needlessly traverse the entire string. Instead, only add markup when you know it is needed.  I don't see any benefit in your trimming and sanitizing because with the exception of `aria-label`, all of the markup is static.

Code:

```
function svg_icon_func(array $atts) {
    static $svgTemplates = [
        'arrow' => '<svg %s %s width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.883 12l-7.527 6.235.644.765 9-7.521-9-7.479-.645.764 7.529 6.236h-21.884v1h21.883z"/></svg>',
        'hamburger' => '<svg %s %s stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m13 16.745c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-9.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h9.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75zm9-5c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-18.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h18.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75zm-4-5c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75h-14.5c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h14.5c.414 0 .75-.336.75-.75z" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>',
        'close' => '<svg %s %s stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m12.002 2.005c5.518 0 9.998 4.48 9.998 9.997 0 5.518-4.48 9.998-9.998 9.998-5.517 0-9.997-4.48-9.997-9.998 0-5.517 4.48-9.997 9.997-9.997zm0 1.5c-4.69 0-8.497 3.807-8.497 8.497s3.807 8.498 8.497 8.498 8.498-3.808 8.498-8.498-3.808-8.497-8.498-8.497zm0 7.425 2.717-2.718c.146-.146.339-.219.531-.219.404 0 .75.325.75.75 0 .193-.073.384-.219.531l-2.717 2.717 2.727 2.728c.147.147.22.339.22.531 0 .427-.349.75-.75.75-.192 0-.384-.073-.53-.219l-2.729-2.728-2.728 2.728c-.146.146-.338.219-.53.219-.401 0-.751-.323-.751-.75 0-.192.073-.384.22-.531l2.728-2.728-2.722-2.722c-.146-.147-.219-.338-.219-.531 0-.425.346-.749.75-.749.192 0 .385.073.531.219z" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>',
    ];

    if (!isset($atts['icon'], $svgTemplates[$atts['icon']])) {
        return null;
    }

    $ubiquitousAtts= [
        'role="img"',
        'focusable="false"',
        'clip-rule="evenodd"',
        'fill-rule="evenodd"',
    ];
    
    return sprintf(
        $svgTemplates[$atts['icon']],
        !empty($atts['label'])
           ? 'aria-label="' . esc_attr($atts['label']) . '"'
           : 'aria-hidden="true"',
        implode(' ', $ubiquitousAtts)
    );
}
```